Failed upgrade on Ubuntu 20.04
Trying to upgrade packages on my virtual ubuntu 20.04 machine.  When i run sudo apt upgrade I get

Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree. 
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 45.2.0-1) but 45.2.0-1ubuntu0.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

When I run sudo apt install --fix-broken

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
python3-setuptools
Suggested packages:
python-setuptools-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
python3-setuptools
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 330 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 python3-setuptools all 45.2.0-1ubuntu0.2
Err:1 http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 python3-setuptools all 45.2.0-1ubuntu0.2
403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/setuptools/python3-setuptools_45.2.0-1ubuntu0.2_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.82 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

When I run sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 45.2.0-1) but 45.2.0-1ubuntu0.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

And I appear to be stuck in this loop.  I'm not sure why i'm getting the 403 forbidden error, I can paste the URL into a browser and connect to it just fine, i can curl the file so i know the firewall at work isn't blocking it or anything.  I've tried using the us.archive.ubuntu.com source as well as a couple of different mirrors based in California (where the server is located) but to no avail.
I have 5 upgradeable packages that I can't finish upgrading because of this issue with the broken python3-setuptools install.

fwupd-signed/focal-updates 1.51.1~20.04.1+1.4-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.27.1ubuntu7+1.2-2~20.04.1]
linux-generic/focal-updates 5.4.0.204.200 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.4.0.137.135]
linux-headers-generic/focal-updates 5.4.0.204.200 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.4.0.137.135]
linux-image-generic/focal-updates 5.4.0.204.200 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.4.0.137.135]
python3-setuptools/focal-security,focal-updates 45.2.0-1ubuntu0.2 all [upgradable from: 45.2.0-1]


Consider fresh installing 24.04. It would be way simpler.

Are you on a VPN, or some kind of proxy? Perhaps it's flagged your VPN provider's IP address as being abusive in some way. If not, I'd keep trying other mirrors, even if they're further away. Better to have a slow download than no download, right?

@ArchismanPanigrahi - I'd like to, it's basically serving as a PIHOLE server for our corporate office but since i'm not in california at that office i'm a little hesitant in case something goes wrong and affects DNS at the office.  I suppose it's just a VM, I could snapshot it just in case.

@TSJNachos117 I've tried a handful of mirrors.  not behind a proxy or VPN.  I can get to the sites just fine in the browser and can download the .deb with curl just fine.

As @buckMurdock42 has stated, I also see the needed package in the HTTP version of the s repository.  Can you get to that site or do you receive a 403 error when visiting in a browser?
